# Remove commas from hashmap

Tags: clojure

I'm using a function that returns a map

```
{:a "A", :b "B"}
```

As you can see it has commas as separators. Is there a simple way to transform this into usual hashmap without commas?:

```
{:a "A" :b "B"}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. Is the problem with the `toString` on maps? How are you getting this text representation of a map?

Comment: The comma is whitespace, and is not part of the data structure. It's just part of the printed output. Are you asking about making a custom printing method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as noisessmith pointed out, there is no (programmatic) difference between those two since `,` is whitespace in clojure source code:

```
user=> (= {:a "A", :b "B"} {:a "A" :b "B"})
true
user=> (map type [{:a "A", :b "B"} {:a "A" :b "B"}])
(clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap)
```

PS: It's up to the underlying pretty-printer (the default clojure one prints `,`) to add `,` to aid readabiliy